# Exception pop up window appears while comparing JSON file to JSON reponse

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am comparing JSON response and JSON File in SOAPUI (ver - 4.6.4, freeware)
Groovy script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.io.File

def ResponseMessage = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Fi - Request 1"].testRequest.response.contentAsString

def jsonResp = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

def jsonFile = new File("C:/Users/new_2.json")
def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseFile(jsonFile, 'UTF-8')

assert jsonResp.equals(InputJSON)
```

But every time it runs a pop up of exception is thrown as:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseFile() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.io.File, java.lang.String) values: [C:\Users\new_2.json, UTF-8]
>   Possible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String) error at line: 12

It didn't work for parseText either. 
Treat it as a beginner scripting.

Now I am facing completely new error -

> groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while    reading '', 
>   no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.error at line: 9

Line 1 of JSON file content: 
{

```
"Metadata": {
    "DocType": "Report",
    "SubType": "",
    "Content": {
        "Title": "Economic Comment",
        "Headline": "",
        "Summary": "",
        "Blurb": ""

    },
    "Priority": "1",
    "DocumentIDs": {
        "DocumentID": {
            "label": "",
            "type": "",
            "level": "",
            "value": ""
        }
    },
```

Note: this content is incomplete. I cannot paste full JSON here due to security reasons

Comment: what is the version of groovy in soapui-4.6.4 ? check the name of the file `SOAPUI/lib/groovy-all-*jar`

Comment: groovy-all-2.1.7

Comment: so check the [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.1.7/html/api/index.html?groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class methods. Something like this should work for you: `new JsonSlurper().parse( jsonFile.newReader("UTF-8") )`

Comment: Now I face a completely different error:

Comment: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading '', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized. error at line: 9. JSON file content as : "Priority": "1",
  "DocumentIDs": {
   "DocumentID": {
    "label": "xyz",
    "type": "xyz",
    "level": "xyz",
    "value": "xyz"

Comment: edit the question and provide the file content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message clearly says the alternatives.

Change below statement:

```
def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseFile(jsonFile, 'UTF-8')
```

To:

```
def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(jsonFile, 'UTF-8')
```

Refer JsonSlurper API from [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)

Comment: The issue occurs after I changed it to >def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(jsonFile, 'UTF-8')

Comment: What issue occurs?

Comment: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading '', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.error at line: 9

Comment: The issue could be with the json file content. Validate your json online and see.

Comment: And the original issue `No signature of method:` is gone. Right?

Comment: No signature of method: is gone. I'll validate my json. Thanks

Comment: the json file content is valid. Verified. But couldn't solve the issue : groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading '', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.error at line: 9

Comment: Can you show the content? or open a text editor, put the content and save as new file and try reading that file.

Comment: Content I have already posted above. I did try reading the content by saving it in separate new file but failed in that attempt as well.

Comment: I think there is some problem with that specific file.. I tried with another file and it worked fine. Thanks for the solution.